# How to find mismatch between two tables with respect to each table in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table TAB_1,TAB_2 which stores the set of some kids with Schema

```
KID_ID (Number(2))  SHIRT_COLOR(VARCHAR (10)) PANT_COLOR(VARCHAR (10)) .
```

TAB_1 has details of 50 kids ,while TAB_2 has 60 records in it .
If we have 45 kids in common between TAB_1 and TAB_2 which have same KID_ID ,SHIRT_COLOR & PANT_COLOR ,Then we have to find out the Mismatches between TAB_1 & TAB_2 w.r.t tables TAB_1 & TAB_2 .

Since 45 kids are common , so there are 5 kids-mismatch in TAB_1 and 15 Kids-mismatch in TAB_2 ,Now we have to check if the 5 extra kids in TAB_1 have any attribute common with the kid of TAB_2 Table i.e. say for instance , if out of 5 kids , 3 kids are there whose shirt match with kids of TAB_2 Table , 2 kids are there whose Pant Color match with the kids of TAB_2 Table ,so there is only 1 kid which is purely extra in TAB_1 Table and there are 11 kids which are purely extra in Tab_2 .

Please guide how to approach this ?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a full outer join here, and then retaining only records from each table which do not intersect between the two tables:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.SHIRT_COLOR, t2.SHIRT_COLOR) AS SHIRT_COLOR,
    COALESCE(t1.PANT_COLOR, t2.PANT_COLOR) AS PANT_COLOR,
    CASE WHEN t2.KID_ID IS NULL THEN 'TAB_1' ELSE 'TAB_2' END AS TABLE_SOURCE
FROM TAB_1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TAB_2 t2
    ON t1.SHIRT_COLOR = t2.SHIRT_COLOR AND
       t1.PANT_COLOR = t2.PANT_COLOR
WHERE
    t1.KID_ID IS NULL OR
    t2.KID_ID IS NULL;
```

Follow the link below to see a running demo in Oracle.

### Demo

Comment: Sir , I want the  Extra kids calculation for each table separately , i.e. On column as Extra_In_Tab_1 and Extra_In_Tab_2 .Also I couldn't get COALESCE Usage here ,it returns first Non-NULL Value but here we have used t1.SHIRT_COLOR ,can there be a  query which doesn't use inline function in it  for the problem statement

Comment: Please review my demo link and then let me know exactly what you would like to see here.  The records I currently display are only the records which are unique to one or the other table.  The records _not_ shown are those which are in common between the two tables, but my assumption is that you don't want to see these records anyway.

Comment: Output has to be Common_Kids   ,   Mismatch_wrt_Tab_1  ,  Mismatch_Wrt_Tab_2  ,     Extra_In_Tab_1 ,     Extra_In_Tab_2                                                                                   for my sample case , op will be   45    ,    5   ,  15     , 1    ,11